# vector which skip's a step

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to create a vector without the number 1 .

```
x=-10:1:10;
```

To avoid this:

```
for(n=0:21)
if(x(n)==1)
x(n)=[];
end
end
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Logical indexing, learn it, love it! `x(x==1)=[]`

Comment: hmm I like this! thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I would use `setdiff`

```
>> setdiff(-5:5,1)

ans =

    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     2     3     4     5
```

Comment: Ah! Nice job on `setdiff`! That's thinking out of the box.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of manually generating a vector from -10 to 10 and removing the entry that has the value of 1, you can always use `colon` / `:` and not include 1 in the vector instead.  Something like:

```
x = [-10:0 2:10];
```

Because it's such a small vector, you probably won't gain much by doing it this way in comparison to fully generating the vector and removing one entry as per David's suggestion.  I do agree with David though.  Learn logical indexing!  It's one of the backbones for making any MATLAB code fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it manually to " ".
eg x(10)=[];